# ruby on rails - User profil page with devise - routing to show profil page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hi I'm facing a bug when I try to implement a link_to my profile page on my navbar. it show me a routing error with the missing key id, it only appear when I put the link on my navbar, otherwise I can access to my profile account.

Here is the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

And this is my code: routes

```
get 'user/show/:id', to: 'user#show', as: 'profil'
devise_for :users
 root 'home#index'
resources :users
```

User controller:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

The application.html where I insert the link making crash my app

```
<%= link_to 'profil', profil_path , class: "dropdown-item" %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes amendment: -

```
root 'home#index'
devise_for :users
resources :users, except: [:show]
get 'user/show/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'profil'
```

> missing required keys: [:id]

Which means in route for `users#show` you need to pass params id as id of user

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) has `current_user` which is the logged in user object so in the `application.htm` Make profil dropdown dynamic say if user is logged in

```
<%if current_user.present?%>
   <%= link_to 'profil', profil_path(id: current_user.id) , class: "dropdown-item" %>
<%end%>
```

Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: i got a undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass when i tried your tricks

Comment: @loba Check the updated answer, it should work , let me know for any further guidance.